# How to properly resize disk usage in docker desktop WSL2?

Tags: docker, wsl-2, diskspace

I am having issues with too much space utilized by docker and wsl2 *.vhdx images.

tried running:

```bash
docker system prune --all
```

Restarting the pc.

Still the vhdx images are too big. In my case the image size grown up to 250GB!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out there is a way to shrink the vhdx images properly in windows:

1. Run in cmd: `docker system prune` (optional `—all`), to clean up disk space
2. Right mouse click on docker desktop in system tray -> quit
3. Run in cmd: `wsl --shutdown`
4. Run `Optimize-VHD -Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx" -Mode Full`, this will resize the vhdx images

Same way you can try to find vhdx images that utilize too much space and optimize them as well. You can use TreeSize(Bing it: Tree Size Windows) to find which image takes the most of the space and optimize them.

P.S. dont forget to run `docker system prune`